# Python: Count Values in multi-value Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I count the number of a specific values in a multi-value dictionary?

For example, if I have the keys `A` and `B` with different sets of numbers as values, I want get the count of each number amongst all of the dictionary's keys.

I've tried this code, but I get 0 instead of 2.

```
dic = {'A':{0,1,2},'B':{1,2}}
print(sum(value == 1 for value in dic.values()))
```

Comment: Try `1 in value` in place of `value == 1` -- in other words, `print(sum(1 in value for value in dic.values()))`

Comment: You mentioned without loop but you are using `for` loop in your example

Comment: Your values are sets. None of them will be equal to 1, which is why the result is always 0.

Comment: Thanks @alani that worked!

Comment: Also, how can I check whether a specific value is in the set of values of a specific key?

Answer (score 1):

[`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a good option for this, especially if you want more than a single result:

```
from collections import Counter

from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(chain(*(dic.values())))
```

In the REPL:

```
>>> count
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 0: 1})
>>> count.get(1)
2
```

`Counter` simply tallies each item in a list. By using `chain` we treat a list of lists as simply one large list, gluing everything together. Feeding this right to `Counter` does the work of counting how many of each item there is.